# Realizar el producto de dos números en "C" - Se cierra la consola

Tags: c

Amigos, acabo de comenzar a aprender lenguaje "C" hace unos minutos, pero tengo un problema que me está poniendo verde. El ejercicio que se plantea es el siguiente:

**Crea un programa que calcule (y muestre) el producto de dos números introducidos por el usuario.**

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int num1,num2,prod;
    printf("Introduce numero A: ");
    scanf("%d", &num1);
    printf("Introduce numero B: ");
    scanf("%d", &num2);
    prod = num1 * num2;
    printf("El producto es: %d",prod);
    getchar();
    return 0;
    }
```

Pero el problema que tengo es que luego de compilar y ejecutar el programa e introducir el segundo valor (Número B), se cierra la consola automáticamente, y no realiza ni muestra el resultado del producto. No tengo idea de cual puede ser el error. Se que es una pregunta muy básica, pero la verdad no he logrado dar con la respuesta. Espero puedan ayudarme, les agradezco a todos por su ayuda.

Comment: Pedro, que IDE estas usando?

Comment: Intenta colocando `system("pause");` antes de `return 0;`

Comment: @Elenasys Estoy utilizando Dev-C++ 4.9.9.2

Comment: @Juan Pinzón amigo de esa manera si funciona, y me he dado cuenta que colocando getchar(); luego de la segunda lectura de datos también funciona ¿A qué se deberá esto?

Comment: Como lo comenta @JuanPinzón debe funcionar (Juan agrega tu respuesta) pero es un poco raro ya que getchar(); debería  funcionar.

Comment: @PedroFumero Por el enunciado de tu pregunta entiendo que esta es una duda sobre C y no sobre C++. ¿Es así? Si lo es habría que borrar el tag C++. Ten en cuenta que C y C++ son lenguajes distintos y que el lenguage C/C++ no existe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Intenta colocando

```
system("pause");
```

antes de

```
return 0;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda :)

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar para pausar la ejecución `system("pause");`:

```
 ...
 ...
 system("pause");
  return 0;
}
```

Puedes usar `cin.get()` para c++ :

```
...
...
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda :)

Comment: `cin` no está disponible para el lenguaje C.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que te está sucediendo es que cuando das la orden de ejecutar el programa tu entorno de desarrollo lanza una consola sobre la que se ejecuta este programa.

Introduces los dos números, tu programa calcula el resultado, lo imprime y después termina. Y cuando termina la consola se cierra inmediatamente.

Entre la impresión del resultado y el cierre pasa tan poco tiempo que no te da tiempo a verlo pero sí que se ejecuta bien y muestra el resultado.

Una solución es la que [expone Juan Pinzón](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/23530/301).

Una alternativa es ejecutar tu mismo el programa. Lanza una consola. En la consola ve al directorio donde esté tu programa compilado y ejecútalo.

Por ejemplo, en Ubuntu lanzo una consola con CTRL+ALT+T y ejecuto estos comandos:

> jose2@HP-Negro:~$ cd codigoFumero/
>   jose2@HP-Negro:~/codigoFumero$ gcc -o ejemplo ejemplo.c
>   jose2@HP-Negro:~/codigoFumero$ ./ejemplo
>   Introduce numero A: 9
>   Introduce numero B: 7
>   El producto es: 63jose2@HP-Negro:~/codigoFumero$

En Windows puedes hacer algo similar usando CMD.EXE

Si esto es un ejercicio académico ten en cuenta que algunos profesores son muy estrictos. Si el enunciado no pone que después de mostrar la multiplicación el programa se quede parando esperando una pulsación de tecla un profesor estricto puede dar por mala tu solución. A mi me ha pasado.